# Karma throw 404 error for a derived controller class

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have just created a derived controller class (defined using type script) and using it in the parent controller class (type script class).

Everything seem to be right but Karma is not able to load this file. Throws 404 error.

Here is the error

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading Path/Controller.js
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading Path/Controller.js
Error loading Path/Controller.js as ".Path/ParentClass.js
```

I have included the class in the parent class we well.

import 'Path/ChildClass';

The Error it throws in browser is as below.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
at directCallParentKarmaMethod (context.js:233)
at ContextKarma.error (context.js:139)
at adapter.js:186
```

But if I just remove this import statement from the controller the Karma tests work fine.

I am guessing this is because the Controller being imported is a child/derived controller.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stupid enough to make problem with a case in file name, but I fixed it now.